# Import Devise 1.1.8 credentials into 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an export of the users table from a Rails 3.0/Devise 1.1.8 app. I would like to seed these into a Rails 3.1/Devise 2.0 app. I imported that data via CSV and configured Devise with the same pepper value as the old app, however users are not able to log in. Bcrypt is/was used in both cases.

I think what I'm missing is that Devise 1 stored the salt in a separate field, but 2.0 puts it in the encrypted password string. Is there a way to migrate my data into the new app properly?

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to follow this:  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0, which basically recommends that you upgrade to 1.5 first, then upgrade all the way to 2.0.  I think its pretty straight forward from that wiki explanation.